# Replacing file from Node_Modules

Tags: angular, npm

I had to modify a file in node modules. which get over written with npm install.
Can I keep modified file in my local src folder? then replace this from node_module while ng serve/ng build.

please help me how can I achieve this.

Comment: if you don't update your node_module local changes of node_module is not changed.

Comment: and why do you want to update node_modules ?

Comment: if update my project in that case @programoholic node_module is also update

Comment: which update ? are you talking about git update

Comment: I had a requirement to modify in node_modules now I want to keep modified file in my src folder and replace it from node_modules when I perform ng serve/ ng build.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this would be to fork the repo.

Here is the link :  https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/.

Using This way, you have control of the contents of the package.

Then update your package.json with your repositpry address.

I also would recommend not pushing your packages to Git. Packages are already under version control (in their own repo) and pushing to Git just bloats your repo for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

As you might already know, we have a package.json file in the project, in which all dependent and development dependent packages are mentioned. We do not push our node_modules folder to the GitHub, instead of that whenever someone downloads our project he simply does npm i, and all the libraries mentioned in the package.json are installed in a new folder called node_modules, even if you make any changes in the node_modules folder it won't get updated on npm from where others will install the packages.

If you want to make any changes in the node_modules folder it won't be saved, all you can do is make changes in your code, (e.g you want to override css of library you have imported, open dev tools look for its class, use host to override the css, or use elementRef (ViewChield) to add or remove class from the element)

Comment: inside node_modules I am using ng-tree module there i modified 1 js file.

is there any option to replace it after new npm install if I have modified file in my src folder?

Comment: I Searched for that package it has 6 weekly downloads if changing the code adds value to that library, contact the contributor raise a Pull request if they accept the pull request your issue will be solved, or you can use some other library else instead of using any library you can write the same code by yourself.